# What is the difference in meaning between both sentences?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> 1.The money is owing.
>
> 2.The money is owed.

I don't understand what is difference of both sentences.

In dictionary has explained that 'Owing meaning is same like owed.' and  Owing and owed is like Due meaning.

However, in my thinking owing is an active meaning but owed is a passive meaning.

Why owing and owed has same meaning like due ?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think there should be a difference between the meaning of these two sentences? There are _other_ uses of the word _owing,_ but in your sentences the two verbs mean the same. Both uses are in the passive voice.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Really? owing and owed have same meaning between them?, So along to your comment I want to know about why the two sentence have to be same meaning.

Comment: Why do you believe that they should _not_ have the same meaning? You can trust what your dictionary tells you.

Comment: @P.E.Dant  Because In my thinking owing is an active meaning but owed is a passive meaning. So, Above two sentences have to be different meaning.

Comment: My first comment was inaccurate. In your first sentence, _owing_ is an adjective, not a verb, and serves as the complement of the copula _is._ In the second, _owed_ is the participle of _owe_ used in a clause in the passive voice. Their meanings, meaning, though, are the same.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.The money is owing.

*Owing* is not a participle as you think, it's an adjective, so it can't mean an action, it refers to a state.

> 2.The money is owed.

*Owed* is a past participle, which also refers to a state. That's why the meaning is the same.